# RDF core module doesn't seem to work after security upgrade

Tags: updating, rdf

I updated from Drupal 7.36 to 7.38 for security reasons. Now the nodes don't get displayed in RDF any more. For example: http://bartoc.org/en/node/112, add .rdf and you get the message "The requested page "/en/node/112.rdf" could not be found." The RDF core module is checked. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [workaround at #9](https://www.drupal.org/node/2142695) that solved the problem for me.

> As workaround, you could use the [RDFa Distiller](http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/) and add the
>   following code to .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on 
+  # call W3C RDFa Distiller to extract .rdf/.ttl/.nt files
+  RewriteRule (.*)\.rdf$ http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1&format=xml [L,R=307]
+  RewriteRule (.*)\.ttl$ http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1&format=turtle [L,R=307]
+  RewriteRule (.*)\.nt$ http://www.w3.org/2012/pyRdfa/extract?uri=http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1&format=nt [L,R=307]
+
   # Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://.  This is used later
   # if you enable "www." stripping or enforcement, in order to ensure that
   # you don't bounce between http and https.
```

> ```
> Many thanks to jneubert!
> ```